# SFTP access to other folders

Tags: mount, permissions, ssh, sftp

My current server setup with 14.04 includes OpenSSH with SFTP configured:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory /mnt/earth/www
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I have a user named `www` who is a member of the group `ftpaccess`.
I have a mounted folder `/mnt/earth/www` that is on another Windows 2008 server.
The folder permissions on this mount are `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 16 10:03 www`

I can connect to my SFTP server with any FTP program, but all I get to see is the user's homedir files:

```
.bash_logout
.bashrc
.profile
```

Not the contents of the mounted folder.

What do I need to change so that this user sees the contents of the mount, instead of his homedir?

Comment: My initial configuration in `sshd_config` is correct. After rebooting the server I can now see the contents of the mount with an FTP application. But I can't write anything to it. I'll have to figure out what may prevent me from writing with this account.

Answer (score 1):

Due to your comment under your question if i understand correctly you solved the main problem but now you ask *" But I can't write anything to it".*

That is why you cannot write > *"drwxr-xr-x 2 **root root** 4096 Mar 16 10:03 www"*

You have to mount /mnt/earth/www with a mask of www user